Coin System - Minimal set of coin nominals to create any value from 1 to 100 with at most 2 coins
I stumbled upon a complex problem that I could not develop any intuition to help me implement the algorithm capable of printing the solution in a finite amount of time.
Problem
In the principality of Potluck, the currency is the Fluke, worth 100 Jammies. The Bank of Potluck has just issued the new One Fluke note but now wants a coin system for the Jammies. The plan is that you should be able to make ANY amount between 1 and 100 Jammies by using just one or two coins. (The two coins can be the same or different.) What is the smallest number of different coins they need for their new system - and what are they?
Here are some sample solutions for a smaller range of Jammies:
Range | Coins Set |
1 to 1 => [1]
1 to 2 => [1]
1 to 3 => [1, 3] or [1, 2]
1 to 4 => [1, 2] or [1, 3]
1 to 5 => [1, 3, 5] or [1, 2, 5] or [1, 2, 4] or [1, 3, 4]
Explanation: For all values between 1 and 5, you can use one of [[1, 3, 5],[1, 2, 5],[1, 2, 4],[1, 3, 4]] coin values to construct any value between 1 and 5 using at most two coins out of the chosen set of coin values.
Concerns: I have tried simple Memo, tries, DP, but none of them seem to work for 1-100 Jammies. The best I got was that the program was jamming on 1-68 Jammies ([1,3,5,7,8,17,18,27,28,30,32,34,35] 13 coins).

@KenWhite The question is about denominations such that every single number can be made from just one or two coins. Nowhere in the question is "just one or two dominations" mentioned or implied.

@KenWhite It can. The trivial case is to have a denomination for every single value, then  every value can be obtained using just one coin. The number of denominations is different from the number of coins you need for each value. The question is asking about the latter. If you are still confused, forget about coins or denominations, rephrase the question as following: What is the mininum length of an array containing integers from 1~99 such that every single integer in 1~99 can be expressed by the sum of at most two elements from the array?

@WeijunZhou: I'm not confused. Having one coin for every denomination is such a ludicrously stupid option that it's not worth consideration.

Maybe the background story is "ludicrously stupid", but the underlying algorithm problem is a valid one.

I don't see why this question is closed. It's a clear-enough stated problem, the author appears to have put some effort into solving it, and it's asking for an efficient algorithmic approach to a non-obvious problem. It looks like homework or a competition problem, but that's not a reason to close.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835313/find-smallest-set-of-natural-numbers-whose-pairwise-sums-include-0-n is essentially the same question (the solutions to the linked problem are exactly 1 more than the solutions to this problem!)

Thank you @PaulHankin, The reference has other very useful references to solving the first part of the problem regarding the number of coins that is required (https://oeis.org/A001212) which is 16. But I still can't see a way to reduce the complexity of searching the coin nominals from exponential.

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122010/pay-each-amount-with-at-most-two-coins

I figured out a solution that is pretty fast but does not take into consideration all the solutions. I noticed that the differences between subsequent coin values are symmetrical.  Based on that I could cut the exploration space in half. Additionally, I assumed that there is always a solution that for 1-N that will require the max coin to be N/2 +- coinDiff. Here is the code: https://github.com/BRUT4LxD/Test_Projects/blob/master/ProblemSolving/CoinExchangeProblem.cs

Correct 1-100 is found in milliseconds but some values require the set the maxDiff to a higher number which slows down the algo. This is still not a complete answer as I cannot prove it guaranties to produce optimal results.
